# How to concatenate a String in EL?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, string-concatenation

How do I get the `promoPrice` variable to print as part of the string `ONLY $4.67`?

```
<c:set var="promoPrice" value="4.67" />
<p>${(promoPrice != null) ? "ONLY $${promoPrice}" : "FREE"}</p>
```

Comment: did my suggestion solve your problem? i.e. move the $promoPrice outside the quotes.

Comment: @rationalSpring no, that doesn't work. I guess you can't pass the variable that way. Thanks though.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you're already on EL 3.0 (Java EE 7; WildFly, Tomcat 8, GlassFish 4, etc), then you could use the new `+=` operator for this:

```html
<p>${not empty promoPrice ? 'ONLY $' += promoPrice : 'FREE'}</p>
```

If you're however not on EL 3.0 yet, then use EL 2.2 (Java EE 7; JBoss AS 6/7, Tomcat 7, GlassFish 3, etc) capability of invoking direct methods with arguments, which you then apply on `String#concat()`:

```html
<p>${not empty promoPrice ? 'ONLY $'.concat(promoPrice) : 'FREE'}</p>
```

Or if you're even not on EL 2.2 yet, then use JSTL `<c:set>` to create a new EL variable with the concatenated values just inlined in value:

```html
<c:set var="promoPriceString" value="ONLY $${promoPrice}" />
<p>${not empty promoPrice ? promoPriceString : 'FREE'}</p>
```

In *your particular case*, another way is to split the expression in two parts:

```html
<p>${not empty promoPrice ? 'ONLY $' : 'FREE'}${promoPrice}</p>
```

If `${promoPrice}` is null or empty, it won't be printed anyway.

Comment: thank you very much! For some reason I couldn't find info anywhere about this kind of concatenation.

Comment: `'str1'.concat(' str2')` fails in EL 2.1 (Tomcat 6)  with this error 
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/x.jsp The function concat must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

Straight jstl way

```
<c:set var="promoPrice" value="4.67" />
<p>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${(promoPrice != null)}">
        ONLY $${promoPrice}
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        FREE
    <c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</p>
```

Comment: I like this version, I was just looking for something a little more compact. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, its a bit verbose but its pretty clear especially if you are using jstl other places

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward and robust solution for string concatenation, that is compatible with EL 2.0+, is to use an intermediate variable:

```
<c:set var="promoPrice" value="4.67" />
<c:set var="priceText" value="ONLY ${promoPrice}" />
<p>${(promoPrice != null) ? priceText : "FREE"}</p>
```

According to [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297285/1429387), starting from EL 2.2 you can do concatenation using `String#concat()` method, and starting from EL 3.0 you can use the new `+=` operator for this.

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this where I have a variable `mathjaxUrl` and I want to contact it other string

```
<c:set var="mathjaxUrl" value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax" />
... some other stuff here
<c:set var="mathjaxUrl" value="${mathjaxUrl}?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" />
```

hope this help you

Answer (score -3):

Won't this work ?

```
<c:set var="promoPrice" value="4.67" />
<p>${(promoPrice != null) ? "ONLY $"${promoPrice} : "FREE"}</p>
```

Notice that the ${promoPrice} is outside the quotes. This looks like the simplest solution.

Comment: Why the -1? Could whoever rated this answer explain?

Comment: this is not legal EL syntax; from the [EL specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) (2.2 mrel): _Nested eval-expressions, such as `${item[${i}]}`, are illegal._