# Compare Java Char to Integer in EL

Tags: jsp, char, integer, jstl, el

I have simple reqirement that I want to compare Java Char to Integer in EL syntax, How do I do it ?

```
<select name="rating" id="id-rating">
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5" > 
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${javaObject.rating == i }">
                <option value="${i }" selected="selected">${i }</option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="${i }">${i }</option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</select>${javaObject.rating }
```

I tried

1. `"eq"` for comaprison
2. varStatus variable 
   eg `loop.index`
3. also `loop.current`

`${javaObject.rating }`  is what  i'm getting from Java Class  ( Spring Controller )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed won't work. The technical problem is, the char `1` has an integer value of `49`. (the code point). Evidence is here:

```
System.out.println((int) '1'); // 49
```

So, you need to add an integer offset to match the char's code point.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="49" end="53"> 
    ${bean.rating == i}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Alternatively, use `<c:set>` with the value in body to convert the value to `String`. EL will then do automatic coercion the right way.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
    <c:set var="ratingAsString">#{bean.rating}</c:set>
    ${ratingAsString == i}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between specifying JSTL <c:set> value via attribute and body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424561/difference-between-jstl-cset-value-in-attribute-and-body-of-tag/34444210#34444210)
- [How to compare a char property in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454261/rendered-attribute-not-working-on-a-character-property/)

Comment: thanks a lot again , you solved my another issue, in which I'm comparing char  from bean to 'Y' or 'N'. previously I converted both to String to get result..
    Your 2nd link is very helpful ...

Comment: Once again, you help me for this, concatenation of String with number,

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6297285/3425489

thanks a lot ,

since I do not have 50 reputation , can't comment over there....

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me

```
${1 eq Integer.parseInt('1')} // return true
```

Comment: I tried but no success.
I am also looking for conversion.