# Concatenate multiple columns in selectOneMenu drop down itemLabel-using facelets

Tags: jsf, facelets

i have the following in my .xhtml JSF:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="raceSelector" value="#manageElectionRace.electionRace.race}" converter="#{RaceConverter}" required="true" requiredMessage="Race Selection is required" valueChangeListener="#manageElectionRace.getValueChanges}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--select--" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{manageElectionRace.racesNotInElection}" var="race" itemValue="#{race}" itemLabel="#{race.raceName}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The drop down right now shows the raceName only, however, I need the drop down to show (concatenate) raceName plus 2 more columns from the same table, say col2 and col3 (if col2 and col3 are not Null)

[![the data][1]][1]

The drop Down should have:

- race1
- race2 **value of Col2:** m , **value of Col3:** n

Note that i also need to display the text in bold **value of Col2** and **value of Col3** in teh drop down

Thank you , appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Please remove this Comment and edit your Question also use code formatting

Comment: Regarding the string concatenation, your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297262/how-to-concatenate-a-string-in-el. Parts bold (effectively a new question) is not possible. This is an html limitation, not a jsf one. You need to use e.g. PrimeFaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate a String in EL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297262/how-to-concatenate-a-string-in-el)

Comment: i'm using facelets and tomhawk, not PrimeFaces, any other suggestion please?