# How to show image on selected item of p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm trying to implement an advanced `selectOneMenu` (PrimeFaces) to choose a locale based on its flag icon. The icons are shown in the list but not for the selected item (the same happens on [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml)). How could I do this?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="mySOMId" value="#{localeBean.locale}" var="mySOMVar" converter="#{localeConverter}" >
    <f:selectItems 
        value="#{myBean.locales}" 
        var="localeSIVar"
        itemLabel="#{localeSIVar.language}" 
        itemValue="#{localeSIVar}" />
    <p:column style="text-align: center;" >
        <h:graphicImage library="default" height="20" name="img/#{mySOMVar.language}.svg" />
    </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I can see that `f:selectItems` has an `itemLabelEscaped` attribute, which I could use to output `<img>` tag in `itemLabel`, but I don't know what I would put on its `src`.

Thanks

Comment: Does putting a static image from somewhere work? I would not expect it to include html. Did you try?

Comment: @Kukeltje do you mean inside `itemLabel`? If so, yes, I just tried putting the following there, and it worked. `itemLabel="&lt;img src='https://someurl/icon.png' height='20' /&gt;" `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `#{resource['library:name']}` syntax to print an URL for the resource, as indicated in [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

So, given that you actually wanted to use a

```
<h:graphicImage library="default" height="20" name="img/#{localeSIVar.language}.svg" />
```

within the `itemLabel`, and that `itemLabelEscaped` attribute of `<f:selectItems>` is set to `true`, then you can use the following syntax as value of `itemLabel`:

```
itemLabel="&lt;img height='20' src='#{resource['default:img/' += localeSIVar.language += '.svg']}' /&gt;"
```

Notes:

- You can only use plain HTML there, not JSF components.
- For improved readability, better use single quotes as attribute value separators within the plain HTML which is in turn declared as an attribute surrounded by double quotes. You can of course also use `&quot;` instead of these single quotes.
- The single quotes continue to work fine in EL expression as shown above, no need for re-escaping. You can even use double quotes within the EL expression, but syntax highlighting in code editors is prone to fail here, potentially causing unnecessary confusion.
- The `+=` operator is new since EL 3.0; in case you're still using an older EL version, head to [How to concatenate a String in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297262/how-to-concatenate-a-string-in-el) for alternate ways to concatenate a string in EL (and then reusing it as a variable).